# jQuery scrollSpeed - on a mousewheel down istead of down it goes up after refresh

Tags: jquery, css

On a website that I built, I have a problem with jQuery and scrollSpeed. The problem occurs when the page is refreshed, and then when I scroll down with my mouse wheel, the page scrolls to top, instead of going down, and after that first scrolling works normal and scrolls down.

Here is what I have in footer:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  
    $(function() {    
        jQuery.scrollSpeed(100, 800);  
    })
});
```

Comment: Just a note im pretty certain your performing two on ready handlers there. Im quite sure passing a function into the jquery constructor `$()` will cause jQuery to call it when the document `ready` is called anyway.

Comment: I tried switching to just once, but it didn't work.